# Find and Replace without a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, replace

I have a large 2-D array in MATLAB, which is updated over time. (something like *A* = (*i*, *j*, *k*), where *k* is time).

I want to find all elements greater than a threshold at time *k*, and replace their value at time *k* - 1.
Is it possible without a `for` loop?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you do it with for loop? Please provide code

Comment: for each `k` you get a new matrix? Or is it okay to have a for-loop on `k`?

Comment: So you want something like `if A(i, j, k) > thr then A(i, j, k - 1) = some_value` for each element in the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = zeros(2,2,3);
A(1,1,2) = -1;
A(1,3,2) = 10;
A(3,3,2) = 15;
%%
k = 2; 
thr = 0; 

[row,col,v] = ind2sub(size(A),find(A >thr))
A(row,col,k) = A(row,col,k-1)

A(:,:, k)%display
```